# Could explain to me the grammar of this sentence? ～てになる

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 「なんで この時は、食べてになるのに、待ってになるんですか? 」みたいな、

What does verb in て form + になる mean here?

Comment: This sentence seeemingly talks about "食べて" versus "待って" (orders, buttons, etc?), and we need more context to figure out what or how exactly these parts work in the sentence.

Comment: This is what they were saying before and after the sentence: 

A: 日本語を勉強してる そこの 現地(げんち)の人から 聞かれるんですけど、答えは 言えるんですけど、教られないなって、


B: めっちゃ むずかしい。


A: そう、せつめいが できない。自分はもう しぜんに しゅうとく しちゃってるから、「なんで  この時は、食べて  になるのに、待って  になるんですか？」みたいな、「その 小さい  っ  なんですか？」って聞かれた時に、えっ！ なんでだろう？ って思っちゃって、それで すごい きょうみもって 勉強はじめたんですね。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your context, the speaker is mentioning specific word forms 食べて and 待って, and they have no grammatical connection with other parts of the sentence. To be a little reader-friendlier:

> 「なんでこの時は、『食べて』になるのに、『待って』になるんですか？」
> *"Why does it become 'matte' while 'tabete' in this case?"*

But few native speakers would be confused by this kind of insertion of a couple raw words without explicit indication.